# Unit step response of a FIR filter

Tags: signal-processing

Given a FIR filter with impulse response:

$$ 
h(n) = \begin{cases}1, &0 \leq n < 5\\
-1, &10 \leq n < 15 \\
0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

What would be the right approach to calculate the filter discrete unit step response?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, Jafar. Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) post about how to ask for help with homework. Also, excellent advice on how to ask a good question in general can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960).

Answer (score 0):

input $x[n]=u[n]$

output 
$y[n]=x[n]\ast h[n]=\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}x[k]h[n-k]$

$$ 
y(n) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}1.1=n+1 \ , &0 \leq n < 5\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{k=4}1.1=5\ , &5 \leq n < 10 \\
\left[5+\displaystyle\sum_{k=10}^{k=n}1.(-1)\right]= 14-n\ , &10 \leq n < 15 \\
0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$